# How to download files using Office Web Add In

Tags: office-js

As long as there are no way to 'Load' an Excel template in the client's Workbook using Javascript API for office, Is it possible to download the file through the browser's Add In? So the user can manually open it.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
    saveFileToDesktop(blob, fileName) {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE only
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = fileName;
            link.click();
        }
    }
```

This was working for me in the following combinations:

Client Windows Office(Excel, PowerPoint) & IE (because that is used in the taskpane)

Client Office Online(Excel, PowerPoint) & IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox

not Working in:

Client Mac Office(Excel, PowerPoint) & Safari (because that is used in the taskpane)

It seems that download goes ok but I was not able to get to the file even tried changing preferences 
File download location: Ask for each download etc. but was not able to get it working.

Comment: After the latest update for Windows 10 the `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` doesn't exist anymore in Outlook desktop client.

Comment: @mirik - after new windows update, our add in is now broken too. were you able to figure out an alternative solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As a solution you can open new window and pass there your file url to the backend:

```
window.open("https://yourbackend.com?fileurl="+encode(url))
```

The backend on its side should act as a proxy and return response with redirect.
This way the Outlook desktop client will open a new tab in a browser and show/download there your file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a document.getFileAsync() API which allows you to get all the slices of the file. For details, see here https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync

Answer (score 0):

The [download](http://danml.com/download.html) library, worked pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty much what you would do with any web application to download files. i would expose that functionality in a dialog shown using our showdialog APIs and also make sure the domain from where you will download the files is in the app domains entry in the Add-in manifest.

Comment: Could u please explain it a little. May be given an example.